# running a test from a main component in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, automated-tests

I need to run a test in angular from the main componenent, I am able to get the code from the user, now I need to test that code from that component or a service and provide feedback to the user. How should I proceed...

Here is my code...

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ace-code-editor

I get the function from the user:

```
  function testThis() {
          console.log("it's working!")
   }
```

now I need to test it and let the user know if the function works as required...

Comment: You don't call the function in the editor, so no result would be returned from the `eval`. Otherwise seems to work as expected.

Comment: I want to run a test om that function at run time...